# How to highlight IPv4 address in iTerm

Tags: regex, ipv4, iterm

A friend recently destroyed a server because he mistyped an IP address, and we thought: how could we make IP addresses clearer to the eye in our day to day Terminal use.

We mostly work from MacOS and use iTerm and connect to remote servers.

### How it started

friend: `I accidentally today destroyed a server because I mistyped an IP address. Oops.`

me: `sorry for your loss...`

friend: `Is there a iTerm2 setting to alwasy highlight/color IP addresses when they are displayed?`

me: `I believe it can be done`

Answer (score 3):

in `iTerm` navigate to `Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Triggers > Edit` and add this regex `[0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})` then select the `Action`: `Highlight Text` or `Highlight Line`.

Make sure the `enable` flag is present and choose `Text` `Background` colors as preferred.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Regex is missing one opening bracket, otherwise great!